# Bottom border on li element

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to add a bottom border to my li elements.
For some reason, no bottom border is added. I can add a border to the right and left, but not the bottom. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.menu {
  text-align: right;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Testimonials</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I see it fine. http://jsfiddle.net/3GupN/

Comment: Looks fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KFCjg/. Do you have more CSS being applied?

Comment: Make sure your UL isn't to small and hiding the bottom of your LI's

Comment: Please provide the css styles for the UL tag. Something there might be throwing the styles off.

Comment: you have to add a UL to the css rule

Comment: Pasted your CSS and HTML as-is into jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/baFf6/ and it looks fine.

Comment: @Nudier - no, you don't.

Comment: BUT! The border does not appear in IE 9's compatibility mode. Adding a right margin, as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/DTrSK/ makes it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try adding;

```
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Your code is working fine ***[here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/HAZKh/)*** without any changes.

Answer (score -2):

This is better:

```
*{
   margin:0;
   border:0;
}
```

Answer (score -6):

I understand clearly about your need. the solutions is given below just change bottom as right. please test and give feedback.

```
.menu li{    
    padding:5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:inline;
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style-position: inside;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```